# rbenv - Error compiling Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, rbenv, digital-ocean

I have problems compiling Ruby on a DigitalOcean Droplet.

rbenv 0.4.0-97-gfe0b243

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Linux bashman 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
rbenv install 2.1.1
```

gives me: https://gist.github.com/astropanic/e4d3a3602612b3c21636

The failure seems to be related to:

```
compiling readline.c
readline.c: In function ‘Init_readline’:
readline.c:1977:26: error: ‘Function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
rl_pre_input_hook = (Function *)readline_pre_input_hook;
^
readline.c:1977:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
readline.c:1977:36: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
rl_pre_input_hook = (Function *)readline_pre_input_hook;
^
readline.c: At top level:
readline.c:634:1: warning: ‘readline_pre_input_hook’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
readline_pre_input_hook(void)
^
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140502004823.5335/ruby-2.1.1/ext/readline'
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140502004823.5335/ruby-2.1.1'
make: *** [

build-ext] Error 2
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9):

The failure to build ruby 2.1 because of readline appears to be a [known error](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526).

I was successful building it using one of the [suggested patches](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526#issuecomment-37933242) like this:

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162.txt | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

Downgrading the readline library to version 6.2.4 is an alternative suggestion but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Also on a DO droplet Ubuntu 14.04. The suggested patches page linked by @Shadwell evidences lots of people with this problem. The above **patch method worked for me for 2.1.0** and looks like it does for some other versions too.

Answer (score 1):

Following will solve your problem:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```